# disability to create new data source

Tags: stimulsoft

I am going to use Stimulsoft Reports.Wpf (Version: 2010.1.700 from 26 March 2010) to prepare some reports but unfortunately **Sometimes** when i want to create a new data source,an error is appeared saying :

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

last time that i saw this thing , i didn't do anything special about it.surprisingly **it was fixed by itself**.But this time it seems it is not going to work.
i have searched the internet 1000 of times but i didn't find anything useful.
what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: When do you get the error? How long the application runs? How many7 reports are shown?

Did you try the latest build?

Answer (score 1):

I Have this problem too. i install some font that was used in report. this problem solved.
or may be because of application cant find stimul soft reports needed dll files.
if reports call from another class library project.

if main exe file and class library report caller has different physical path in  windows you have to copy stimulsoft report files into main exe file path and also into report caller dll path too.